# Is there a CSS element that will let me add a space?

Tags: html, css, asp-classic

I am at an impasse with this page I am trying to modify for my institution. The page is somewhat proprietary and not all of the files that comprise the page are accessible to me. The only things I can get access to are 5 different files called a `stylesheet`(naturally), a `head`, a `top`, a `bottom`, and a `print`

So this is the page:

http://s5-sandbox.parature.com/ics/support/default.asp?deptID=15028

The issue is that below the page where you have the 2 sections for "Viewed Most Popular Topics" and "Most Recent Topics", is that the words `ViewedMost` run on together. Additionally the number of views and the first word of the actual topic respective of the views run on together. For example, you'll see `3869What is my Blackboard Username and COM ID?`

Given the pages that I have access to, none of them have the ID for that section declared in them. It is in some `.ASP` page on Parature's backend. I've contacted their support and put in a ticket and did not receive any resolution. I tried emailing someone directly and a man told me something ridiculous:

> *If you right click on the area and click inspect element you are able to add a space either behind “view” or in 
>   front of “most”. Either works, I’ve tried them both. The same goes for the number and the article.*

I already know full well how to use the Chrome inspector but what I told this gentleman was that I don't have access to the page to add a space nor do I even know if there is an element I can use to fix the formatting. I was hoping you guys would be able to see something I do not on the page that would allow me to create the space that I am looking to add.

Thank you all.

Comment: `.item { padding-right: 5px; }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.item:after {
content: "\00a0";
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Is there anyway to increase the gap in between them without affecting the items in the section area of "Most Recent Topics"?

Comment: Yes. it would be: `.mostpopular .item:after` instead than `.item:after` in the code above

Comment: I didn't know specifically applying additional elements to very specific things could be as easy as how you made it be. Your solution to the problem taught be how to apply it to other things on the page. Thank you very much.

Comment: you're welcome. I learnt that stuff 1 week ago :) very useful :)

Comment: Worth to mention in your answer that [it's not supported in IE8 or less](http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/) - according to [this](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php) over 10% of the people are still using IE7 or IE8 which is LOT of people where this code won't work for them.

Comment: Right, but the question was how to add a space via CSS. If the question was how to add space (without the article a) then there would have been a broader x-browser compatibility.

Comment: @Pikk then what is the solution for broader x-browser compatibility?